# How to convert SpaceView3d.lens to field-of-view?

Tags: export

I'm trying to export data of the User Perspective Camera to a [LibGdx Camera](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html). As far as I know there's no way to get the field-of-view of the User Perspective Camera directly.

Thanks to whoever can help me with this.

Edit:

@Jerryno:

Thanks for your reply. I tried your approach, using this code.

```
import bpy
import math
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils

def area_view_3d():
    areas = [a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == "VIEW_3D"]
    if not areas:
        return
    return areas[0]

def camera_angle(a3d):
    region = [r for r in a3d.regions if r.type == "WINDOW"][0]
    r3d = a3d.spaces[0].region_3d
    if r3d.view_perspective == "ORTHO":
        return
    ray_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, r3d, (0, 0))
    view_camera_loc = r3d.view_matrix.inverted().translation
    look_at = r3d.view_location
    view_local_z = look_at - view_camera_loc
    return math.degrees(view_local_z.angle(ray_vector))

a3d = area_view_3d()
if a3d:
    #a3d.spaces[0].lens = 16
    print(camera_angle(a3d))
```

Comment: Sorry, correct is `view_local_z = look_at - view_camera_loc`, the vector was opposite direction so the correct angle was 180-angle. Now I tested it with empties placed at viewport camera location, center of viewport and corner of viewport with the script and measuring angle - it is now correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert *focal length* to *field of view* you need to know the sensor size. The formula is as follows:

```
FOV = 2 * arctan(half_the_diagonal_of_sensor / focal_length)
```

See this in [Blender's code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/math_rotation.c;72dd1ba3fe67206680ef3540b681d944e8bb4872$2006).

So that means your *field of view* is dependent on the size and aspect ratio of the *3d View* window.

Best way how you could approach this is to cast a ray into the scene from one 3d window corner and measure the angle to the ray that is in center of screen (basically to the local Z axis of viewport).

- you get the 3d rays like this (snippet from a modal operator - you will have to overwrite context for your application):

  ```
  import bpy
  from bpy_extras import view3d_utils

  region = bpy.context.region
  rv3d = bpy.context.region_data
  pixel_coords = (0,0)

  ray_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, pixel_coords)

  view_camera_loc = rv3d.view_matrix.inverted().translation
  look_at = rv3d.view_location
  view_local_z = look_at - view_camera_loc
  ```
- you measure the angle between the `ray_vector` and `view_local_z`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the field of view of a view3d would be:

```
vmat_inv = region3d.view_matrix.inverted()
pmat = region3d.perspective_matrix @ vmat_inv
fov = 2.0*math.atan(1.0/pmat[1][1])*180.0/math.pi;
```

This actually uses the formula provided in the other answer 
(would have posted as comment, but got no reputation  )